# Why docker container name has an random number at the end?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

I have a docker-compose.yml file as below (a piece of it):

```
version: '3.5'
services:
    framework:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/gme/fmk:${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}
    build: ./fmk
    ports:
      - "2020:2020"
      - "2025:2025"
      - "4999:4999"
    volumes:
      - ${FOLDER_ENV}/workspace/logs/framework:/var/log/gcti
      - ${FOLDER_ENV}/..:/usr/local/genesys/gsg_qaart
```

what I got is:

```
vagrant@docker:/repos/gsg_qaart/docker$ docker-compose ps
]              Name                             Command               State                                             
Ports
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
callback_framework_1_df361f67842c   /bootstrap.sh                    Up      0.0.0.0:2020->2020/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2025->2025/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4999->4999/tcp, 5432/tcp
```

As you can see the name is weird, it supposes to be "callback_framwork_1", why there is a random number at the end?

BTW, I'm using:

```
vagrant@docker:/repos/gsg_qaart/docker$ docker -v
Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4
vagrant@docker:/repos/gsg_qaart/docker$ docker-compose -v
docker-compose version 1.23.1, build b02f1306
```

Thanks.

Comment: what's the output of `docker ps`?

Comment: e743b462e56c        gme/fmk:callback                "/bootstrap.sh"          2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:2020->2020/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2025->2025/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4999->4999/tcp, 5432/tcp        callback_framework_1_2d34e5dc1703

Comment: I am also getting this after I just updated to the latest docker version. It broke my scripts because I can no longer count on the container name being constant

Comment: I guess this broke LOADS of scripts (including the ones of my team, of course). No wonder they rolled it back in less than a month.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT.

This change is reverted in v1.23.2

---

So there is an important change in the compose v1.23, https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.23.0

> The default naming scheme for containers created by Compose in this
>   version has changed from project_service_index to
>   project_service_index_slug, where slug is a
>   randomly-generated hexadecimal string. Please make sure to update
>   scripts relying on the old naming scheme accordingly before upgrading.

Therefore if you want to have a deterministic container name, use

```
services:
    framework:
        container_name: framework
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot hardcode container name and I want to be able to run from any directory. So I ended up grepping part of the name:

```
docker exec -it $(docker ps --format='{{.Names}}' | grep server) bash
```

Answer (score 0):

*Note, the other answers/troubleshooting are valid/correct, but I'd like to give some food for thought on working with docker-compose, despite how docker-compose reverted the slug change. There is a good practice that can be highlighted in in making use of docker-compose services.*

My personal thoughts are docker-compose was attempting to pursue a shift in how their tool was being used. I read somethings on github that hinted at that, but that's my opinion after reading some of their developers feedback, specifically from the following [github issue on the slugs](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6316).

## Making use of docker-compose's internal service mechanisms

I'm attempting to generalize, since the following examples may not be fully applicable to your setup, but they should be helpful none the less. Since you're already using docker-compose, there is a benefit to using service discovery provided via docker networks and docker-compose over hard-coding access via container names.

When using docker-compose, services are created that are composed of 1..* containers. In your example, the service `framework` is created with 1 container `callback_framework_1_df361f67842c`.

### Accessing a service from within another docker container/code in a docker container

A service can be used for DNS/networking instead of container names, that is everywhere `<protocol>://<host>:<port>/<endpoint>` where the `container name` was used as the `<host>`, the `service name` can also be used as the `<host>` (eg executing ping inside of another container on the docker network):

```
ping <service>
ping framework
```

vs

```
ping <container-name>
ping callback_framework_1_df361f67842c
```

Both the above pings work. Docker takes care of the networking to the appropriate container, farther when there are multiple containers that compose a service, it takes care of load balancing requests to the containers.

### Accessing your containers via service from the host machine, ie running docker commands from scripts

Addressing if you have scripts executing from the host machine, you can also make use of docker-compose instead of docker commands as well:

```
docker-compose exec <service> sh
docker-compose exec framework sh
```

vs

```
docker exec -it <container-name> sh
docker exec -it callback_framework_1_df361f67842c sh
```

docker-exec defaults to the first container, but when there are multiple containers that compose a docker service, a target container can be addressed using the `--index=<index>` flag. See [docker-compose exec documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/exec/) for more details.