# How to adapt to new slug numering scheme in version 1.23?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

With version 1.23.0 of [docker compose](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases) the container naming scheme changed.

> Important note
>
> The default naming scheme for containers created by Compose in this version
>   has changed from project_service_index to
>   project_service_index_slug, where slug is a randomly-generated
>   hexadecimal string. Please make sure to update scripts relying on the old
>   naming scheme accordingly before upgrading.

Every time I call `docker-compose up -d` the `slug` is newly generated.

My problem: Inside on of my containers I have a PowerShell script (`build_container`) that performs SVN operations on a second container (`container_svn`). Since the container name is part of the SVN-URL my scripts are broken. Reason: The old SVN-URL was e.g. http://container_svn_1/repos. Based on the slug change my `build_container` is not able to connect to `container_svn_1` anymore, since the SVN container seems to be only reachable under `container_svn_1_someRandomSlug`.

With docker-compose < 1.23.0 is was able to ping the `container_svn` from `build_container`via

```
PS C:\> ping container_svn_1
```

Now with docker-compose > 1.23.0 I've to use:

```
PS C:\> ping container_svn_1_c298f27bdf5c
```

How can I inject "container_svn_1_c298f27bdf5c" as the name of `container_svn` in the `build_container`? Is it possible to inject the name via an environment variable?

Thx

Comment: Since you're using docker-compose, I'd encourage you to access containers within a given service instead of the container directly (ie `http://svn/repos` instead of the `http://<container name>/repos`). There is a suite of docker-compose alternatives to access containers like via `docker-compose exec ... <service>` instead of `docker exec ... <container_name>`. Additional note from within the containers on a docker network instead of `ping container_svn_1` it'd be `ping svn` which is cleaner all around anyway. Just some food for thought.

Comment: For anyone stumbling across this, I elaborated how to adapt on the linked [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53326899/why-docker-container-name-has-an-random-number-at-the-end), though I don't believe the questions are duplicates. the linked question is asking why is there slugs, this question is asking how do I adapt to slugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to fix the container name using "container_name" parameter (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#container_name). If you use "scale", this won't work.

You can also use links to alias your container (https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#links).

Regards,

Comment: "Links are a legacy option. We recommend using networks instead."

Comment: Any way, this has been fixed in 1.23.2 (https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/release/CHANGELOG.md). Slug will be used for docker-compose run (which is a good practice).