# Docker-compose: why does the number appended to services not increment?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container

**Please help me understand the number that is suffixed to services spun up by `docker-compose`.**

From [docker-compose image named: "prefix_%s_1" instead of "%s"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33045358/docker-compose-image-named-prefix-s-1-instead-of-s) and [Why docker container name has an random number at the end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53326899/why-docker-container-name-has-an-random-number-at-the-end), I formed the understanding that the number is an integer incremented with each instance of that service.

I think that understanding is incorrect because, with this experiment, I'm trying to spin up multiple instances of a detached service, but the suffixed number is always "_1":

```
# Dockerfile
FROM alpine:3.15 as base
```

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.6'
services:
  dummy:
    build:
      context: .
```

```
$ docker-compose up --build --detach
WARNING: The Docker Engine you're using is running in swarm mode.

Compose does not use swarm mode to deploy services to multiple nodes in a swarm. All containers will be scheduled on the current node.

To deploy your application across the swarm, use `docker stack deploy`.

Building dummy
[+] Building 0.3s (5/5) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                          0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 43B                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:3.15                                0.0s
 => CACHED [1/1] FROM docker.io/library/alpine:3.15                                           0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                        0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                       0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:35e223a20dbce8c0b81d3257f8cad0c7b2b35d8e18eadfec7eeb7de86a472e7b  0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/docker-compose_dummy                                       0.0s
Successfully built 35e223a20dbce8c0b81d3257f8cad0c7b2b35d8e18eadfec7eeb7de86a472e7b
Recreating docker-compose_dummy_1 ... done
$ docker-compose up --detach
WARNING: The Docker Engine you're using is running in swarm mode.

Compose does not use swarm mode to deploy services to multiple nodes in a swarm. All containers will be scheduled on the current node.

To deploy your application across the swarm, use `docker stack deploy`.

Starting docker-compose_dummy_1 ... done
$ docker-compose up --detach
WARNING: The Docker Engine you're using is running in swarm mode.

Compose does not use swarm mode to deploy services to multiple nodes in a swarm. All containers will be scheduled on the current node.

To deploy your application across the swarm, use `docker stack deploy`.

Starting docker-compose_dummy_1 ... done
$
```

Comment: The number increments when you use the `--scale` option to create multiple instances of a service (`docker-compose up --scale dummy=3`).

Comment: @larsks -- was my experiment was invalid? Was I not manually creating three instances of the dummy service (i.e. the manual equivalent of the `--scale` arg)? My understanding is super shaky here, but I thought that by spinning up "detached" services, they were running in the background, and therefore `docker-compose up` would spin up a new instance of that service -- not true? Grateful if you can expand on your comment in an answer, or if you know of good reading material -- I've trawled google hits, but nothing has quite helped me grok this yet.

Comment: Normally `docker-compose up -d` tries to ensure that the containers listed in the `docker-compose.yml` are running; it will not start new containers if they are already running in the described state.